# How to write out debug messages in one pane of MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm migrating some SQL Server procedures to MySQL.

There are "print" statements throughout the MS-SQL code (used for debugging on the backend as necessary), but I understand that they have to be converted to "SELECT messages" in MySQL. But when executed in MySQL Workbench (on windows), the output of each SELECT shows up in a separate resultset tab, as opposed to the "print" statements which output debugging lines in the messages pane of SSMS.

Is there any way to get the debugging output to show up in the same tab when executed in SQL Workbench?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this is not possible at all with standard tools.However one possible way might be to use a UDF (user defined function) that prints out a string and call that with the DO command (which prevents the SELECT from returning a resultset) like:

```
DO SELECT print_string('warning');
```

I haven't tried that myself. It's just an idea to try out.

To get started you may find here some ideas for UDFs: https://github.com/mysqludf.

Comment: I would love to try out your idea, but I don't know how to (or understand what you mean by) create a UDF that "prints out a string". What command would I do that with?

Comment: I surmise you're referring to using a different language like python/C to develop the UDF. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think that's possible or else somebody would have already developed this UDF and released it to the community by now, since it seems there is a lot of demand for such an animal but no solutions I've found as of yet.

Comment: Writing a MySQL UDF involves to write a library (in any programming language which can create loadable libraries, but usually it's done in C or C++). Here is one idea to write output in an UDF: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8822555/how-to-debug-mysql-user-defined-function.