# SQL: What am I doing wrong? adding / sum returns null

Tags: mysql

Totally MySQL newbie here. I'm a network systems management student and I have a problem with one of the exercises.

The exercise asks to create a function that returns the total amount of cash earned by a car repair shop given a specified month.

Previously I had to create two functions, one that calculates the total cost of the spare parts used in a repair (totalRecambios), and other that calculates the total cost of the worktime in a repair (ManoDeObra). Both of the functions work well.

I've created this code

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION RecaudaMes(mes int)
RETURNS decimal(6,2)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
DECLARE totalmes decimal(6,2) DEFAULT 1;
DECLARE idrp INT;
DECLARE ultfila INT DEFAULT 1;
DECLARE totalconceptos decimal(6,2);
DECLARE Cursor1 CURSOR FOR SELECT idreparacion FROM reparaciones WHERE month(FechaEntrada)=mes;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE "02000" SET ultfila=0;
OPEN Cursor1;
FETCH Cursor1 INTO idrp;
WHILE ultfila=1 DO
SELECT sum(ManoDeObra(idrp)+TotalRecambios(idrp)) INTO TotalConceptos;
SET totalmes=totalmes+Totalconceptos;
FETCH Cursor1 INTO idrp;
END WHILE;
CLOSE Cursor1;
RETURN Totalmes;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

My problem is that it always returns a NULL. I don't know why. I think the problem is related with the SET totalmes=totalmes+totalconceptos statement.
Because if I set the function to return totalconceptos, y returns a number.

So please! What am I doing wrong????
Thanks!!!

Comment: Try `SET totalmes + 0` before you open the cursor? I think that we need to see the previous code, the table defintions and some sample data.

Comment: Does `ManoDeObra()` or `TotalRecambios` may return NULL? If true then wrap them with `COALESCE()` (separately!).

Comment: Hi! No, nor totalRecambios() or ManoDeObra() return NULL. TotalRecambios() multiplies the number of units of a given spare part ID (idrp) for the number of units used. ManoDeObra() does the same but multiplying the cost of a procedure for the number of hours used. Both functions work correctly in every repair.

Comment: When I substitute SELECT sum(ManoDeObra(idrp)+TotalRecambios(idrp)) INTO TotalConceptos; with SELECT 10 INTO TotalConceptos; I cannot reproduce your error https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8be1c9b3ad317936f33cb1ad682a6fc7 which points at the first select and functions not behaving as expected. You really need to prove your assertion by publishing the functions and sample data as text.

Comment: Did you try to Debug your function? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-windows-excerpt/5.7/en/visual-studio-debugger.html  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8822555/how-to-debug-mysql-user-defined-function